# WPF MVVM: Strange Binding behavior

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, tabcontrol

I have a `UserControl` that contains a `TabControl`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.MyUC"
....
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModels"
         xmlns:ikriv="clr-namespace:IKriv.Windows.Controls.Behaviors"

...

<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:MyUCVM x:Key="VM" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="VM" />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<!-- Using Ivan Krivyakov's Attached Behavior -->
<TabControl ikriv:TabContent.IsCached="True"
            TabStripPlacement="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding TabList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyTab1VM}">
            <v:MyTab1/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyTab2VM}">
            <v:MyTab2/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
...
```

Of course, in `MyUCVM`, I have `TabList`. Now, up to this point, everything works fine.

The problem starts when one of the tabs (e.g. MyTab1) in the `TabControl` needs to continuously and recursively read data from some external source (done in the `ViewModel` of course), and pass that data to `View` (via `Binding`) to display. Even up to this point everything is working. However, I do not want that to run when the tab is not visible, because there is no point to do that.

To do that, `MyTab1VM` needs to know if the associated View (`MyTab1`) is the selected tab. Therefore, I wired this up:

```
MyTab1:
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
</Style>

MyTab1VM
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(MyTab1VM),
    new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(IsSelectedChanged))
    );

public bool IsSelected
{
    get
    {
        return (bool) GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
    }
}
public static void IsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Property == IsSelectedProperty)
    {
        MyTab1VM vm = d as MyTab1VM ;

        vm.SetupToGetData();
    }
}
private void SetupToGetData()
{
    if (this.IsSelected)
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }
}
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsSelected)
        this.MyData = ExternalSource.GetData();
    else
    {
        (sender as System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer).Stop();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this setup only works when I set `this.IsSelected = true;` manually in the `MyTab1VM`'s constructor. Leaving that out in the constructor, the data do not get shown in the view.

I have set breakpoints and confirmed that the binding for `IsSelected` is running correctly. Even the timer is running, and `ExternalSource.GetData()` is being called. But `this.MyData = ExternalSource.GetData();` is not triggering the change from the ViewModel to the View.

The most puzzling part is that the same binding is triggered if `IsSelected` is set to `true` from the constructor.

Anyone out there knows what happened here?

Comment: please check what happened whed you define the next <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}" />?

Comment: What do you mean by "next"? I tried switching to TwoWay mode and explicitly specifying the trigger to be on PropertyChanged, the result is the same.

Comment: look I'm just tried to help. so the problem is - when the timer tick is happened the IsSelected if false. Is it correct?

Comment: After 2 to 3 hours of step in/over/out line by line, I have a slightly better clue now. It has nothing to do with IsSelected. It probably has to do with how I bind the Tabs' viewmodels to the tabs (views).

Comment: let me know if you still need a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do some fruitful troubleshooting on my own. I made a breakpoint in `SetupToGetData()` and I put `this.GetHashCode()` in my debugging watchlist. When I manually set `this.IsSelected = true` in the constructor, I realized that the `SetupToGetData()` method is called twice, with two different hash values. Planting another breakpoint in the constructor also showed that the constructor is called when I switch to this tab.

I have decided to move this to a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109760/wpf-mvvm-setting-datacontext-of-tab-views), because it looks highly possible that the problem has nothing to do with binding.

### Edit

Seems like I was right that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109760/wpf-mvvm-setting-datacontext-of-tab-views) is the root of this problem. As that question is solved, so is this as well.