# WPF MVVM: Setting DataContext of Tab Views

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, tabcontrol, datacontext

I have experienced a weird binding behavior that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37068521/wpf-mvvm-strange-binding-behavior). I did a lot of troubleshooting and I came to the conclusion that the most likely problem lies at how I set the `DataContext` of each of the tab's view.

I have a `TabControl` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to a list of `ViewModels`.

```
MainView:
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabList}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Tab1ViewModel}">
            <v:Tab1 />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
...
</TabControl>

MainViewModel:
public ObservableCollection<TabViewModelBase> TabList { get; set; }
public MainViewModel()
{
    this.TabList = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModelBase>();

    // Tab1ViewModel is derived from TabViewModelBase
    this.TabList.Add(new Tab1ViewModel()); 
}
```

So, now the `MainViewModel` has a list of `TabViewModelBase`, which I believe is the correct MVVM way to do this. The view (`Tab1`) for `TabViewModelBase` is defined using `DataTemplate`.

This is where the problem is:

```
Tab1:
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:Tab1ViewModel x:Key="VM" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="VM" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

I think most people would do this as well, but...
There is something **terribly wrong** with this approach!

In `MainViewModel`, I have manually instantiated a `Tab1ViewModel`. In `MainView`, I used `DataTemplate` to tell the View to use a `Tab1` whenever it sees a `Tab1ViewModel`. That means `MainView` would instantiate an object of `Tab1` class.

Now, `Tab1` needs its `DataContext` to do binding with its own `Tab1ViewModel`, so we use `StaticResource` to add one `Tab1ViewModel`, except that this is a brand new instance!

I need to set the `DataContext` back to the original one that I instantiated in `MainViewModel`. So, how do I set the `DataContext` of `Tab1` within `DataTemplate`?

Comment: just remove all the Resources and DataContext code you show for Tab1. your Viewmodel instance is in your Collection and the DataTemplate is defined in your TabControl Resources

Comment: Then my `Tab1` would have no `DataContext`, and I would not be able to do any binding between `Tab1` and `Tab1ViewModel`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to specify `vm:Tab1ViewModel` new instance in your XAML. Neither do you need to define the `DataContext` explicitly. Every item of your list is a `ViewModel` whenever the type of a `ViewModel` matched with the type you have defined in `DataTemplate` a particulate `view` will be rendered and with the same `DataContext` as `ViewModel`. For example if list has two objects like below:

```
public ObservableCollection<TabViewModelBase> TabList { get; set; }
public MainViewModel()
{
    this.TabList = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModelBase>();
    this.TabList.Add(new Tab1ViewModel1()); 
    this.TabList.Add(new Tab1ViewModel2()); 
}
```

and your `DataTemplate` is :

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabList}">
<TabControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Tab1ViewModel}">
        <v:Tab1 />
    </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Tab1ViewModel2}">
        <v:Tab2 />
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

...

> ***then Two tabs will be renders `Tab1` & `Tab2` (cause list has 2 items). `Tab1` will have `Tab1ViewModel1`as `DataContext` and and `Tab2` will have
>   `Tab1ViewModel2` as `DataContext`. You need not specify `DataContext`
>   explicitly.***

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't believe the solution is soooooo simple. Now I feel like hitting myself on the head -.-

Comment: @Jai it can get confusing sometimes for DataTemplate, almost everyone does it the way you were trying. you can find countless equations on SO about same. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to @KyloRen's answer: This is so called "**ViewModel-First approach**". Based on your viewmodel, view is selected -> you have viewmodel first.

However, you don't even need datatemplates for your views. It can be annoying to write datatemplate for each view.

There is alternative implementation of the same "ViewModel-First" principle:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabList}">
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content={Binding Converter={ViewModelToViewConverter}} />
     </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

`ViewModelToViewConverter` takes ViewModel and based on naming convention creates view for it. This is especially usefull in page-based navigation scenarios, but it is universal approach that works in many situations (navigation, listboxes, itemscontrols, dynamic content presenters, etc..)

Example of the converter can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31721236/475727) - just replace the IocContainer with `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: Actually, I am using `Activator` approach to open new `Windows` as well. But sometimes I feel that this is a bit "hackish" though.

Comment: If you have a good reason for it, for example the above mentioned namig convention, it's not hackish. If you have naming convention, that couples views and viewmodels and need to specify datatemplates that couples views and viewmodels again, it's kind of DRY principle violation